# Multi-domain configuration

Tags: config, multi-site, multi-domain

We have a multi-(sub)domain setup within a single Craft CMS and single `.env` file: `insights.xximo.com` and `www.xximo.com`.
Sometimes when visiting `insights.xximo.com` we get errors like:

```
Access to script at 'https://www.xximo.com/dist/assets/app.089fed21.js' from origin 'https://insights.xximo.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.xximo.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

This is caused by the Craft-Vite plugin which in the [config#47](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-vite/blob/develop/src/config.php#L47) uses    `'serverPublic' => App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL') . '/dist/'` to set the path to the assets.

I know there is a way to use different configurations depending on the `environment` but is there also a way to differentiate configurations depending the `site(handle)`?

I tried loading `craft\console\Application` into the config and using `Application->sites->currentSite->handle === 'insights' ? App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL') : App::env('INSIGHTS_SITE_URL')` but that doesn't seem to be allowed or working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this a little bit. This is nothing more than a CORS issue, you can simply resolve this by adjusting your nginx or apache config to also allow the origins for the subdomain from your `www` subdomain.

Comment: I asked the server host to look into this but somehow there was no way.
In the end I ended up removing the `App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL') . ` from the setting so I always used the domain you're on.